# Is the router feature "Hairpin NAT" a security risk?

Tags: router

My router has this feature under port forwarding. Is it safe to enable it?

Comment: Inherently, not. But it is very broad thing and it depends on the circumstances. Is the color of my cap a security risk? It might be - for example, if I sign with it to the laser interferometry eavesdroppers in the next building, which windows should they target with their device.

Answer (score 3):

Hairpin NAT just means that the external IP of the NAT router is also accessible from the internal IP address - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) for more details. While one might probably construct an unusual use case where hair pinning is a security problem it is not a security problem in the usual use cases. Still, if you don't need this option you might just leave it off.